# Simplification of complex amplitudes

Tags: complex-arithmetic

In a previous answer the following identity was presented

$$-i \vec \kappa \exp^{[i\vec \kappa \cdot (\vec r_j - \vec r_i)]} = -\vec \kappa \sin[\vec \kappa \cdot (\vec r_j - \vec r_i)] \, .$$

Why does it hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cited source for this claim is also wrong, it is in general not true that $iz=Im(z)$ or similar. What happens in the context is that there is a summation containing both signs in the exponent. So
$$
x\exp(iwx)+(-x)\exp(iw(-x))=2ix\sin(wx)=ix\sin(wx)+i(-x)\sin(iw(-x)).
$$
Or in other words, the real part in $x\exp(iwx)$ is an odd function. In a symmetric summation it accumulates to zero, only the imaginary part gives a non-trivial result.